# I am getting the following error: Codeigniter 3 too few arguments error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi I am trying to update a record but I get this error:

> "An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: ArgumentCountError Message: Too few arguments to function  Complaints::update_workplace_incident(), 0 passed"

controller function

```
    public function update_workplace_incident($enquiry_id)
        {
    
            $response = array();
    
            if($enquiry_id) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('edit_practitioner', 'Practitioner', 'trim|required');
                $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
    
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                    $data = array(
                        'practitioner' => $this->input->post('edit_practitioner'),
                    );
    
                    $update = $this->model_certification->update_workplace_incident($data, $enquiry_id);
                    if($update == true) {
                        echo "
                        <script> alert('Success')
                        window.location='https://kiruidavid.co.ke/osha/auth/login'
                        </script>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "
                        <script> alert('Failed')
                        window.location='https://kiruidavid.co.ke/osha/auth/login'
                        </script>";         
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $response['success'] = false;
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        $response['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
                    }
                }
            }
```

model function

```
    public function update_workplace_incident($data, $enquiry_id)
    {
        if($data && $enquiry_id) {
            $this->db->where('employer_complaint_id', $enquiry_id);
            $update = $this->db->update('company_complaints', $data);
            return ($update == true) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you actually pass a parameter to the controller from your form?  We don't know because we cannot see your form.  Your payload appears to be POST submission.  Is `enquery_id` in that payload?  If so, then you don't need to nominate the parameter in your controller method's signature.  What do you see in `var_export($this->input->post()); exit();` if you write that as the first line inside of your controller method?  Also, `update()`'s third parameter can be an associative array representing the WHERE clause conditions. Since `update()` returns a boolean value, you can directly `return` that.

Answer (score -1):

lets try add the != null in first line in your controller function
from this ...

```
public function update_workplace_incident($enquiry_id)
```

to this ...

```
public function update_workplace_incident($enquiry_id != null)
```

Comment: Why would it be ideal to pass a boolean value where an enquiery_id is expected???

Comment: it just condition where to make a sure the $enquery_id has a value, some case there is a variable not bring value in their function, that's why he has error message like that

Comment: ...no, it doesn't "make sure the `$enquery_id` has a value".  You probably mean `(?int $enquiry_id = null)`.  However, this doesn't solve the problem if the value is logically expected, but not delivered.